# Changing a value of first data frame for rows that match with 2nd data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if first data frame `df1` is:

```
     'a' 'b' 'value'
0     1   2     1
1     2   3     1
```

and second data frame `df2` is

```
     'a' 'b' 
0     1   2
```

I would like to get something like

```
     'a' 'b' 'value'
0     1   2     0
1     2   3     1
```

For all the rows in df1(excluding 'value' column) that match the rows in df2, I would like to change the 'value' column of these rows in df1 from 1 to 0. I can find the common rows by using `df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b'])`. But how do I change the value?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want to change the values? You could do df1.merge(df2, on=['a','b'])['vaule'] = new_values, thought I'm not certain if this change will be in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `indicator` parameter to be true when `merging`, this will generate an extra column specify if the rows come from both sides, and then you can modify the value column based on the `_merge` column:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how = "left")
df_merge["value"] = df_merge["value"].where(df_merge['_merge'] != "both", 0)
df_merge.drop("_merge", axis=1)

#    a   b   value
#0   1   2       0
#1   2   3       1
```

---

Another option:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['a', 'b'])
df1.loc[df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index, 'value'] = 0
df1.reset_index()

#   a   b   value
#0  1   2       0
#1  2   3       1
```

Comment: Hi, for the first option, do you mean `df_merge["value"] = df_merge["value"].where(df_merge['_merge'] == "both", 0)`, because if the rows exist in both dataframes, I would like to change the value to 0.

Comment: Hmm. Almost, however, *pandas.Series.where* keeps the value, when the condition is true, and takes the other(here 0) when the condition is false. So you want to keep the value, if it is `left_only`. I know it is a little counter intuitive, but this is how this function works.

Comment: Yea that's a bit counter intuitive hahaha, I notice that when implementing your code. Thanks a lot anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the common rows using the inner join.

```
df1.merge(df2, how= "inner", left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

If you want the output you posted then you can use left join

```
df2.merge(df1, how="left", left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

You can replace nan value with zero.